# How to obtain reduced cost in the graphical sensitivity analysis?

Tags: linear-programming, sensitivity-analysis, reduced-costs

According to some tables in the book Operations Research by Hamdy Taha(7th edition), it seems that **for a variable whose optimal value is zero**, reduced cost can be evaluated by the following formulas:

reduced cost = MaxObjCoeff - CurrObjCoeff (**for max problems**)

and

reduced cost = MinObjCoeff - CurrObjCoeff (**for min problems**)

I should note that the interval [MinObjCoeff, MaxObjCoeff] is the optimality range of CurrObjCoeff in the graphical sensitivity analysis.

I wonder if these formulas always work? Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: The reduced cost can be calculated as $C_j-Z_j = C_j-C_bB^{-1}a_j$. Where $C_j$ is the current objective coefficient and $C_b$ is the objective coefficient in the basic matrix. Now, for any non-basic variables, it might be positive or negative, depending on the direction of the objective function. For example, in the minimization problem, to move a variable into the basic, it needs to have the negative reduced cost and vice versa. Would you please, say what you mean by Max or Min object coefficients?

Comment: @A.Omidi The interval [MinObjCoeff, MaxObjCoeff] is the optimality range of CurrObjCoeff.

Comment: Are you sure you got those formulas correct? Given the order of subtraction, your first formula (max - current) implies a nonnegative reduced cost and your second formula implies a nonpositive reduced cost. A positive reduced cost for a nonbasic variable implies a minimization problem and a negative reduced cost implies a maximization problem, so line 1 must be for a min problem and line 2 for a max problem ... but having an upper (lower) limit on the objective coefficient of a nonbasic variable occurs in a max (min) problem, which is backwards from what you have.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand suppose $z= 6x+2y-1$ then max of z would be at
$x,y=(6,0)$ for x bounded by $[0,6]$ and $y=[0,3]$. Imagine z is the negative sloping line or contour in x-y plane.
Slope of contour z is -3. What's the minimum amt by which coeff of y to be increased to make value of $y>0$ and increase max value of z? In other words how much slope needs to be reduced to make y a basic variable.